# Failed to resolve: com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer

Tags: android, android-studio, referrer

Regards to https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/google-play-referrer-api-track-and.html

Play Install Referrer Library 1.0 now available

> To make it easy to integrate the Install Referrer API, we've released the Install Referrer Library 1.0 for Android. The library is available in our Maven repository. To start using it, add the following dependency to your app module build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
      ...
      compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
  }
```

However it gives me error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes I know, I have no problem to make it duplicate but it will give quick response to this question in Google search :)

Answer (score 5):

Be sure you have added `google()` in your project root, a.e.:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
        // instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
    } }
```

---

It's not mentioned in their DOCs

Comment: Sir, Visit here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html